# Closure in subspaces.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand how the closure of a set changes when it is considered as subset of different spaces. Specifically, what's the difference between $\bar{Z}^Y$ and $\bar{Z}^X$ in the example below? If we use the definition that the closure of a set $A$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points, then how does whether $Z$ is a subset of $Y$ or $X$ affect that description?

[image]

---

Edit: my goal is to prove the statement $\bar{Z}^Y = \bar{Z}^X \cap Y$, but I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z$ is a subset of $Y$. We can consider it as subset of the topological space
$(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$, where $\mathcal{T}_Y=\{O \cap Y: O \in \mathcal{T}_X\}$ is the subspace topology that $Y$ inherits from $X$, or just as a subset of $(X,\mathcal{T}_Y)$.

Taking the closure in the first space will give a subset of $Y$ (by definition) denoted by $\overline{Z}^Y$, and taking just the closure in $X$ we denote it $\overline{Z}^X$ (the $X$ to emphasize we're taking the closure in $X$) and will be a subset of $X$ (so can contain points not in $Y$).

As a concrete example, in $X=\Bbb R$, usual topolgoy, we can take $Y=(0,1)$ and $Z = (0,\frac12)$. Then $\overline{Z}^Y=(0,\frac12]$ while $\overline{Z}^X=[0,\frac12]$.

General fact though, in this situation:

$$\overline{Z}^Y = \overline{Z}^X \cap Y$$

Comment: I'm trying to prove this exact statement and getting a bit confused.

Comment: @ensbana this is pretty obvious if you see the closure of $Z$ as the smallest closed subset (of the space we’re considering it to be in) that contains $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

For example assume $Z$ is a non closed set in $X$. Take $Y=Z$, we get that $\overline{Z}^Y=Z$ and $\overline{Z}^X=\overline{Z}\ne Z$.

Comment: If we use the definition that the closure of a set $A$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points, then how does whether $Z$ is a subset of $Y$ or $X$ affect that description?

Comment: The definition is that "the closure of a set A *in a space X*, is the union of A and its limit points *in X*."